# Virtual memory- don't fully-understand why we need it beyond security reasons?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

In several books and on websites a reason given for virtual memory management is that it allows only part of a program to be loaded in to RAM and therefore more efficient use of RAM is made.

1) Why do we need virtual memory management to only load part of a program? Why could we not load part of a program using physical addresses?

2) Beyond the security reasons for separating the different parts (stack, heap etc) of a process' memory in to various physical locations, I really don't see what other benefits there are to virtual memory?

3) Why is it important the process thinks the addresses are continuous (courtesy of virtual addresses) when in reality they are discontinuous?

EDIT: I know the obvious reason that virtual memory allows more memory to be treated as if it were RAM.

Comment: Try running a program that needs 16G in a computer with only 8G of RAM.

Comment: (Without virtual memory there are many other ways to do this, mostly involving "overlays".  But they are rarely a better way.)

Comment: Imagine that addresses in your city were assigned randomly, with 213 4th St being next to 952 Walnut St, etc.  Without some sort of automated "translation" of address to physical coordinate you'd have a very difficult time finding your way around.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't understand why the underlying physical memory addresses must be "un-ordered" (as you put it in your analogy)?

Comment: Imagine that the folks building the houses picked the locations they wanted looking at an idealized map of the city, with one person picking a location here on a hill and another there overlooking a late, but then the houses, for efficiency reasons, were built next to each other starting at one corner of the city.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think these analogies are working :) Let me re-word my question, what is to stop all the physical memory addresses for a particular process from being continuous (at the physical level)?

Comment: Physical addresses often are contiguous.  But you fit part of the logical address space here, another part there.  Virtual memory handles things so that if I want to access 732 Oak Street that location will be "paged in", even if it's not already in real memory.  So I don't have to keep track of physical addresses.

Comment: Imagine if the code, on every instruction, had to check "Is the next instruction already in memory?  If not go page it in and jump to that location."

Comment: @mezamorphic-Kindly upvote OR if too satisfied,accept the answer for same reason.OR if you've any doubt,please leave a respective comment below any of the answer for the author!

Comment: @mezamorphic - I've noticed that you neither upvoted any of the answers, nor accepted one. I request you, if any answer resolves your query, at least, please upvote and accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why do we need virtual memory management to only load part of a
>   program? Why could we not load part of a program using physical
>   addresses?

Well, you obviously are aware that programs' size can range from some KB's to several GBs or even more than that. But, as we have kind of a limitation on our main memory aka RAM (because of cost issues), so the whole program bigger than the size of RAM can't be loaded as whole at once. So, to achieve the desired result scientists (computer scientists) developed a method `virtual memory`. It'd help to achieve

a) first `space equal to size of some portion of hard-disk(not total),but the major part that would easily accomodate parts of running program`. Say, if the running program's size exceeds the size of RAM, then the program is kinda cut into segments (not really), only the relevant part which could easily fit into memory is called, and the subsequent codes are called as per address by address in sequence or as per instruction call!

b) less burden on physical memory and thereby enabling other programs in the main memory to keep running. Well there are several more reasons!

> 2) Beyond the security reasons for separating the different parts
>   (stack, heap etc) of a process' memory in to various physical
>   locations, I really don't see what other benefits there are to virtual
>   memory?

Separation of heap,stack,etc. is for storing several kinds of operations running at times. `They all are different data-structures and hence they will be storing possibly different program's values or, even if similar program's values, then also distinct instruction sequence's address`! Say, stack would be storing a recursive call's return address (the calling address) whereas the heap would be pointing at current code of execution of the program!

Also, it is not the virtual memory which has this storage scheme but it's actually fit in the main memory. Also,there are several portions of heap also, which performs different functions entirely! Also, I already mentioned benefits of virtual memory -- helps in running several programs simultaneously,optimises caching, addressing using `paging`, `segmentation`, etc.

> 3) Why is it important the process thinks the addresses are continuous
>   (courtesy of virtual addresses) when in reality they are
>   discontinuous?

Would it be better in the world `if there had been counting like 1,2,3,4,5,etc. which we are familiar or had it started like 1,5,2,4,3, etc. even though knowing the true pattern rejecting the choice to render it discontinuous?` Well, at least I'd have chosen the pattern option to perform any task. Similar is the case with physical (main) memory! The physical memory renders the exact address and it clearly fetches the addresses in a dis-continuous manner -- kinda mingled.

But wait, WOW, we have a mechanism like `virtual memory` which has led to the formation of the `actual discontinuous memory locations` to a fixed `regular/continuous memory location`! Virtual memory using paging, segmentation has made the work same, but to make us understand easier. Also,due to relative indexing in paging and due to segmentation -- the address/memory location appears continuous though the actual address is always determined the paging scheme or segment's starting address! Hence, the `virtual-memory` renders as if we are working with a continuous memory location. Isn't it good/better!

Comment: @mezamorphic- I hope it clears your doubt!If you have any query/question,please feel free to point at!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of advantages to using virtual memory over strictly physical memory, some of which you've already listed. Basically it allows your programs to just use memory without having to worry about where it comes from or what else might be competing for it. It makes memory appear to be flat and contiguous, even if it's spread out across various sections of physical memory and to disk.

> 1) Why do we need virtual memory management to only load part of a
>   program? Why could we not load part of a program using physical
>   addresses?

You can try that with purely physical addresses, but what if there's not a large enough single block available? With virtual addresses you can bridge sections of physical RAM and make them appear as one large block. You can also move things around in memory without interrupting processes that would be surprised to have that happen.

> 2) Beyond the security reasons for separating the different parts
>   (stack, heap etc) of a process' memory in to various physical
>   locations, I really don't see what other benefits there are to virtual
>   memory?

It also helps keep memory from getting overly fragmented. Makes it easier to segregate memory in use by one process from memory in use by another.

> 3) Why is it important the process thinks the addresses are continuous
>   (courtesy of virtual addresses) when in reality they are
>   discontinuous?

Try iterating over an array that's split between two discontinuous sections of memory and then come ask that again. Or allocating a buffer for some serial communications, or any number of times that your software expects a single chunk of memory.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why do we need virtual memory management to only load part of a program? Why could we not load part of a program using physical addresses?

Some of us are old enough to remember 32-bit systems with 8MB of memory. Even compressing a small image file would exceed the physical memory of the system.

It's likely that the paging aspect of virtual memory will vanish in the future as system memory and storage merge.

> 2) Beyond the security reasons for separating the different parts (stack, heap etc) of a process' memory in to various physical locations, I really don't see what other benefits there are to virtual memory?

See #1. The amount of memory required by a program may exceed the physical memory available.

That said, the main security reasons are to separate the various processes and the system address space. Any separation of stack, heap, code, are usually for convenience and error detection.

Advantages then include:

1. Process memory in excess of physical memory
2. Separation of processes
3. Manages access to the kernel (and in some systems other modes as well)
4. Prevents executing non-executable pages.
5. Prevents writing to read only pages (code, data).
6. Easy of programming

> 3) Why is it important the process thinks the addresses are continuous (courtesy of virtual addresses) when in reality they are discontinuous?

I presume you are referring to virtual addresses. This is simply a matter of convenience. It would make no sense to make them non-contiguous.